# тестирование, junit

Tags: java, junit

Дана функция:

```
public void configure() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jmjrst, "Hallo-SWT1-Plugin", "Info", 
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Хочу написать тестовый класс, который проверяет было ли вызвано окно (в противном случае исключение). Выглядит как-то так:

```
public void testСonfigure() {
        try {
            foo.configure();
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            fail();
        }
    }
```

И все было бы замечательно, если бы окно закрывалось автоматически после прогонки теста. Как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void testСonfigure() {
    try {
        foo.configure();
    } catch (HeadlessException e) {
        fail();
    }finally{
           Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(label);
           win.setVisible(false);        
    }
}
```

если верхний код не сработает, то вот полный пример снизу

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AutoCloseJOption {

    private static final int TIME_VISIBLE = 3000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("My App");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(100, 100);
        frame1.setLocation(100, 100);

        JButton button = new JButton("My Button");
        frame1.getContentPane().add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Title");
                dialog.setModal(false);
                dialog.setVisible(true);

                new Timer(TIME_VISIBLE, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        frame1.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: если часто будешь вызывать, то можно в tearDown() вызывать закрытие